# Introducing a blank area in the header with a0poster

Tags: minipage, posters, sciposter

I'm writing a poster with `a0poster` and have to make the poster according to the [conference instruction](http://secretariat.ne.jp/ibc2012/information_for_speakers.html). In the header, left of the title, I have to leave some space so that the organizing committee can insert information, but I couldn't do it.

Below is the code I'm using. How can I modify it to introduce the space?

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,epsfig,multirow}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[divps]{psfrag}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{maybemath}
\newcommand{\nx}{\ensuremath{\mbox{\boldmath$x$}}}
\newcommand{\nX}{{\bf X}}
\newcommand{\vbeta}{\ensuremath{\mbox{\boldmath$\beta$}}}
\newcommand{\vtheta}{\ensuremath{\mbox{\boldmath$\theta$}}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\ensuremath{{\mbox{\it{\tiny T}}}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{I\!\!R}}

% Definition of some variables and colors
\setlength{\columnsep}{4cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

%%%  Background
\newcommand{\background}[3]{
    \newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
    \newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
    \psframe[framearc=0.1,fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
  gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
}

%%%  Poster
\newenvironment{poster}{
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
}{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}

%%%  pcolumn
\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
}{
  \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
}

%%%  box
\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
#4
\end{minipage}
}}

\begin{document}

\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}
\vspace*{5.5cm}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
     \definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.9,0,0.9,0}
     \definecolor{whitegreen}{cmyk}{0.3,0,0.3,0}

\begin{poster}

%%% Header
\begin{center}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.99}

\pbox{0.95\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.3,linecolor=darkgreen,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{

%%% Unisiegel
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \scalebox{1.0}{\includegraphics{LogoUSP.EPS}}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
%%% Title
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.78\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
      {\sc \begin{LARGE}\textbf{TITLE}\end{LARGE}}\\[10mm]
    {\Large Author1$^{1}$, Author2$^{1}$ and Author3$^{1}$\\[7.5mm]
    $^{1\,}$University\\[7.5mm] e-mail1; e-mail2; e-mail3}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
%%% GK-Logo
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \scalebox{0.6}{\includegraphics{LogoIBS.EPS}}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

}
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}

\vspace*{4.5cm}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\baselineskip 32pt

\begin{center}\pbox{.8\columnwidth}{}
{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=darkgreen,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=whitegreen,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
{\begin{center}\begin{Large}\textbf{Introduction}\end{Large}\end{center}}\end{center}\vspace{1.0cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1.
\item 2.
\item 3.
\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems to me, that there is more than enough space left of the title. Do you want to have the title moved further to the right in contrast to being centererd? Also in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) you should strip away everything that is not related to the actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly; you can decrease the width of the box reserved for the title and authors and add a `minipage` before this box; this `minipage` will give you the area reserved to be used for the Institution; something along the lines of the example code below (I corrected some spurious blank spaces in the original code, but I'm not sure that I corrected them all (I didn't have the time)):

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,epsfig,multirow}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[divps]{psfrag}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{maybemath}
\newcommand{\nx}{\ensuremath{\mbox{\boldmath$x$}}}
\newcommand{\nX}{{\bf X}}
\newcommand{\vbeta}{\ensuremath{\mbox{\boldmath$\beta$}}}
\newcommand{\vtheta}{\ensuremath{\mbox{\boldmath$\theta$}}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\ensuremath{{\mbox{\it{\tiny T}}}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{I\!\!R}}

% Definition of some variables and colors
\setlength{\columnsep}{4cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

%%%  Background
\newcommand{\background}[3]{%
    \newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
    \newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
    \psframe[framearc=0.1,fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
  gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
}

%%%  Poster
\newenvironment{poster}{
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
}{
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{center}%
}

%%%  pcolumn
\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
}{
  \end{center}
  \end{minipage}%
}

%%%  box
\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{%
\psshadowbox[#3]{%
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
#4
\end{minipage}%
}}

\begin{document}

\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}
\vspace*{5.5cm}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
     \definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.9,0,0.9,0}
     \definecolor{whitegreen}{cmyk}{0.3,0,0.3,0}

\begin{poster}
%
%%% Header
\begin{center}
\begin{pcolumn}{.99}
\begin{minipage}[t][9cm][t]{.24\textwidth}
\centering
{\bfseries\Huge SESION No.\par}
This is the space that will be used by the Secretariat to add some information
\end{minipage}\hfill
\pbox{\dimexpr.65\textwidth-1cm\relax}{9cm}{%
  linewidth=2mm,
  framearc=0.3,
  linecolor=darkgreen,
  fillstyle=gradient,
  gradangle=0,
  gradbegin=white,
  gradend=white,
  gradmidpoint=1.0,
  framesep=1em}%
{%
%%% Unisiegel
\begin{minipage}[t][9cm][c]{0.1\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{LogoUSP.EPS}
\end{minipage}\hfill
%%% Title
\begin{minipage}[t][9cm][c]{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
      {\sc \begin{LARGE}\textbf{TITLE}\end{LARGE}}\\[10mm]
    {\Large Author1$^{1}$, Author2$^{1}$ and Author3$^{1}$\\[7.5mm]
    $^{1\,}$University\\[7.5mm] e-mail1; e-mail2; e-mail3}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}\hfill
%%% GK-Logo
\begin{minipage}[t][9cm][c]{0.1\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{LogoIBS.EPS}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]